# how to make image blur in android

Tags: android, image-processing

hi i m trying to implement some effect on image like image border and some color various 
and now i m trying to make blur image like this

[image]

the center part of image is clearly visible and other part are blur

hear is the link witch i refer 
http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/VariableBlurFilter.html

but its different from this image(this lib in java so i convert BufferdImage to bitmap but now it's out of my mind) can any one help me in this..

Comment: What parts of the image do you want to blur? Do you want it to be like the example picture where there is a single clear area (like a circle) and then blurred outside of it?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the late reply. I forgot to check stackoverflow this weekend.

Anyway, what I think you should do is something like this (it's been simplified to grayscale, but should be easily made to work for RGB):

```
oim = original image
xc, yc = center point
d = distance from center point for in-focus
fval = zeros, matrix size of oim
max_blur = maximum blur radius
for all pixels (xp,yp) in oim
    dist = sqrt((xp-xc)^2+(yp-yc)^2)
    dist = dist-d // we only care about the area beyond the clear area
    if dist>0
       blur = dist
    end
    if blur>max_blur
       blur = max_blur // this can also be scaled or whatever works for your needs
    end
    blur = round(blur)
    fval(xp,yp) = blur
end
nim = oim
for b=1:max_blur
    blurred = blur_function(oim,b)
    for all pixels (xp,yp) in fval
       if fval(xp,yp) == b
          nim(xp,yp) = blurred(xp,yp)
       end
     end
end
```

nim is now new image

So basically what happens here is that we first make a sort of lookup table that tells us how much to blur a given pixel. The focus values are a function of each pixel's distance from the clear area. This is the matrix fval. We then blur the image multiple times and each time update the new image with the new pixel data from the blurred image, and only update a given pixel if we are updating for that de-focus level.

The blur_function can be anything. When I tested this myself, I used average blur in MatLab.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for reply but i m new and at my level it's to difficult for me (i m so sorry to say) have u done(find) any example. ones again thanks.

Comment: @Youddh

I'm afraid I don't have any other example. As I said, I developed this version myself. So what you see is pretty much what I have (I may also have the MATLAB code, but it's virtually the same).

What part is giving you trouble? I can really only advise you on this algorithm itself, not on Android image processing.

Answer (score 2):

Download JHLabs Library for Android from the following link. These libraries will work on Android.

- https://code.google.com/p/android-jhlabs/
- https://code.google.com/p/android-jhlabs/downloads/list