# Transparent blurry view which blurs layout underneath

Tags: java, android

I've got a Linearlayout which I've made transparent, and now I'm looking for a way to give it a Blur effect, so what's ever underneath it gets blurry. Just like the Windows 7 Aero look (see screenshot).

I know you can do a blur effect like this:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

But this only applies to like blurring the background when a dialog appears.

I've been googling for almost an hour, and I can't find anything. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks

[image: Windows 7 Aero effect]

Comment: This might not "blur" exactly, but you could set a background color with a relatively low alpha value. For example white in xml: `#88ffffff"`.

Comment: Looks a lot of work to implement, and possibly for the processor, but this could be an option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033615/image-processingblur-effect-in-android . Basically you would get a screenshot, make a blurred copy, then show covered section as the background.

Comment: @anthropomo probably not the way to go for me since the view underneath is gonna change frequently, but thanks

Comment: FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND is deprecated now :), can you tell more about what will be behind this layout?

Comment: I'm working on a floating app, you know like the app airCalc or overscreen browser. And I would like the top bar with the window title and controls (close, maximize, minimize) to look like is does in windows 7. So just about anything is gonna be behind it.

Comment: Try to use this library I think you just need to pass the view on it and it will work... https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This was on my mind for some time, and I just implemented it thanks to your question.

To be able to do this, we need to draw the layout that is beneath our blur layout into a bitmap. Than by using a blurring algorithm, we need to blur that bitmap and finally draw blurred bitmap as our blur layout's background.

Luckily android has cached drawing mechanism, so first part is easy. We can simply enable cached drawing for our beneath layout and use `getDrawingCache()` to acquire the bitmap from it.

Now we need a fast blurring algorithm. I used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028267/3133545

Here it is.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

/**
 * A drawable that draws the target view as blurred using fast blur
 * <p/>
 * <p/>
 * TODO:we might use setBounds() to draw only part a of the target view
 * <p/>
 * Created by 10uR on 24.5.2014.
 */
public class BlurDrawable extends Drawable {

    private WeakReference<View> targetRef;
    private Bitmap blurred;
    private Paint paint;
    private int radius;


    public BlurDrawable(View target) {
        this(target, 10);
    }

    public BlurDrawable(View target, int radius) {
        this.targetRef = new WeakReference<View>(target);
        setRadius(radius);
        target.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        target.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_AUTO);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (blurred == null) {
            View target = targetRef.get();
            if (target != null) {
                Bitmap bitmap = target.getDrawingCache(true);
                if (bitmap == null) return;
                blurred = fastBlur(bitmap, radius);
            }
        }
        if (blurred != null && !blurred.isRecycled())
            canvas.drawBitmap(blurred, 0, 0, paint);
    }

    /**
     * Set the bluring radius that will be applied to target view's bitmap
     *
     * @param radius should be 0-100
     */
    public void setRadius(int radius) {
        if (radius < 0 || radius > 100)
            throw new InputMismatchException("Radius must be 0 <= radius <= 100 !");
        this.radius = radius;
        if (blurred != null) {
            blurred.recycle();
            blurred = null;
        }
        invalidateSelf();
    }


    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    }


    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    /**
     * from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028267/3133545
     * <p/>
     * <p/>
     * <p/>
     * Stack Blur v1.0 from
     * http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html
     * <p/>
     * Java Author: Mario Klingemann <mario at quasimondo.com>
     * http://incubator.quasimondo.com
     * created Feburary 29, 2004
     * Android port : Yahel Bouaziz <yahel at kayenko.com>
     * http://www.kayenko.com
     * ported april 5th, 2012
     * <p/>
     * This is a compromise between Gaussian Blur and Box blur
     * It creates much better looking blurs than Box Blur, but is
     * 7x faster than my Gaussian Blur implementation.
     * <p/>
     * I called it Stack Blur because this describes best how this
     * filter works internally: it creates a kind of moving stack
     * of colors whilst scanning through the image. Thereby it
     * just has to add one new block of color to the right side
     * of the stack and remove the leftmost color. The remaining
     * colors on the topmost layer of the stack are either added on
     * or reduced by one, depending on if they are on the right or
     * on the left side of the stack.
     * <p/>
     * If you are using this algorithm in your code please add
     * the following line:
     * <p/>
     * Stack Blur Algorithm by Mario Klingemann <mario@quasimondo.com>
     */
    private static Bitmap fastBlur(Bitmap sentBitmap, int radius) {


        Bitmap bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);

        if (radius < 1) {
            return (null);
        }

        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();

        int[] pix = new int[w * h];
        Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
        bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

        int wm = w - 1;
        int hm = h - 1;
        int wh = w * h;
        int div = radius + radius + 1;

        int r[] = new int[wh];
        int g[] = new int[wh];
        int b[] = new int[wh];
        int rsum, gsum, bsum, x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw;
        int vmin[] = new int[Math.max(w, h)];

        int divsum = (div + 1) >> 1;
        divsum *= divsum;
        int dv[] = new int[256 * divsum];
        for (i = 0; i < 256 * divsum; i++) {
            dv[i] = (i / divsum);
        }

        yw = yi = 0;

        int[][] stack = new int[div][3];
        int stackpointer;
        int stackstart;
        int[] sir;
        int rbs;
        int r1 = radius + 1;
        int routsum, goutsum, boutsum;
        int rinsum, ginsum, binsum;

        for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
                p = pix[yi + Math.min(wm, Math.max(i, 0))];
                sir = stack[i + radius];
                sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);
                rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);
                rsum += sir[0] * rbs;
                gsum += sir[1] * rbs;
                bsum += sir[2] * rbs;
                if (i > 0) {
                    rinsum += sir[0];
                    ginsum += sir[1];
                    binsum += sir[2];
                } else {
                    routsum += sir[0];
                    goutsum += sir[1];
                    boutsum += sir[2];
                }
            }
            stackpointer = radius;

            for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {

                r[yi] = dv[rsum];
                g[yi] = dv[gsum];
                b[yi] = dv[bsum];

                rsum -= routsum;
                gsum -= goutsum;
                bsum -= boutsum;

                stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
                sir = stack[stackstart % div];

                routsum -= sir[0];
                goutsum -= sir[1];
                boutsum -= sir[2];

                if (y == 0) {
                    vmin[x] = Math.min(x + radius + 1, wm);
                }
                p = pix[yw + vmin[x]];

                sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);

                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];

                rsum += rinsum;
                gsum += ginsum;
                bsum += binsum;

                stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
                sir = stack[(stackpointer) % div];

                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];

                rinsum -= sir[0];
                ginsum -= sir[1];
                binsum -= sir[2];

                yi++;
            }
            yw += w;
        }
        for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            yp = -radius * w;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
                yi = Math.max(0, yp) + x;

                sir = stack[i + radius];

                sir[0] = r[yi];
                sir[1] = g[yi];
                sir[2] = b[yi];

                rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);

                rsum += r[yi] * rbs;
                gsum += g[yi] * rbs;
                bsum += b[yi] * rbs;

                if (i > 0) {
                    rinsum += sir[0];
                    ginsum += sir[1];
                    binsum += sir[2];
                } else {
                    routsum += sir[0];
                    goutsum += sir[1];
                    boutsum += sir[2];
                }

                if (i < hm) {
                    yp += w;
                }
            }
            yi = x;
            stackpointer = radius;
            for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                // Preserve alpha channel: ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] )
                pix[yi] = (0xff000000 & pix[yi]) | (dv[rsum] << 16) | (dv[gsum] << 8) | dv[bsum];

                rsum -= routsum;
                gsum -= goutsum;
                bsum -= boutsum;

                stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
                sir = stack[stackstart % div];

                routsum -= sir[0];
                goutsum -= sir[1];
                boutsum -= sir[2];

                if (x == 0) {
                    vmin[y] = Math.min(y + r1, hm) * w;
                }
                p = x + vmin[y];

                sir[0] = r[p];
                sir[1] = g[p];
                sir[2] = b[p];

                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];

                rsum += rinsum;
                gsum += ginsum;
                bsum += binsum;

                stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
                sir = stack[stackpointer];

                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];

                rinsum -= sir[0];
                ginsum -= sir[1];
                binsum -= sir[2];

                yi += w;
            }
        }

        bitmap.setPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

        return (bitmap);
    }

}
```

Usage :

```
View beneathView = //the view that beneath blur view
View blurView= //blur View

BlurDrawable blurDrawable = new BlurDrawable(beneathView, radius);

blurView.setBackgroundDrawable(blurDrawable);
```

And how my test application looked like:

[image: test application]

*I decided not to use this tho, because it is too hacky and not looking as cool as i thought it would be in first place.*

Comment: Great answer! This is however, as I understand it, not able to live-blur any changes that happens to the layout behind it, as windows 7 does - but, I guess this is a limitation, at least to most android devices, because it would probably take an enormous amount of power to blur the background say 30 times per second... I'm gonna except your answer though, cause it is good and probably as close as you can get. Cheers!

Comment: You can add 

`if (blurred != null) {
            blurred.recycle();
            blurred = null;
        } 
        invalidateSelf();`

at the end of the `draw` method to update it for any live changes but you won't even get close to real-time. Maybe with using some fast native blurring algorithm it might be possible tho.

Comment: Second thought, live updating it might cause memory issues in low end devices better not to do.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Thanks again

Comment: If there is no way to blur dynamic content behind the view I will give you the bounty.

Comment: @Ayoub I found this http://nicolaspomepuy.fr/blur-effect-for-android-design/ . Using the same blurring algorithm but there is an interesting idea, we don't have to work on original image. And it says by using half or quarter of the original image, processing time decreased from 2 seconds to 200 milliseconds. Still not realtime of course but promising. Also it is just a background, 1 or 2 frame per second might be optimum I think. Also for api level 17 and later there is RenderScript which is worth a look. So there is a way but requires experimenting and well defining your needs.

Comment: cool, I will try them both. Your solution is enough for what I need, but a lighter/more dynamic one is also appealing.

Comment: @onur The view is appearing transparent instead of blurring for me. I have a button on top of imageview. This is what I've done  BlurDrawable blurDrawable = new BlurDrawable(imageview, 50);
        btnAbove.setBackgroundDrawable(blurDrawable); .

Comment: @SudheeshMohan It's been a while since I wrote this code and it is hard to answer without seeing your code but one thing pops into my head that you set an image for your ImageView and that image is opaque, right?

Comment: @onur yes. The image is opaque. (A wallpaper)

Answer (score 74):

Blurring in real time on android is still a hurdle. Here's a comprehensive comparison between some of the viable mechanisms:

> **StackBlur** (already listed in the answer by `Onur` under the moniker `fastBlur`):

How it looks (at radius 20):

[image]

Logged time(ms) to generate each `BitmapDrawable`:

```
I/(10266): Total time taken: 35
I/(10266): Total time taken: 54
I/(10266): Total time taken: 48
I/(10266): Total time taken: 36
I/(10266): Total time taken: 48
I/(10266): Total time taken: 39
I/(10266): Total time taken: 49
I/(10266): Total time taken: 50
I/(10266): Total time taken: 35
I/(10266): Total time taken: 47
```

Average => ~ 44.1 ms => 22 drawables per second

> **RenderScript**:

`ScriptIntrinsicBlur` provides a consistently fast blur. Its available api 8 onwards using the support library.

What it looks like (at radius 20):

[image]

Logged time(ms) to generate each `BitmapDrawable`:

```
I/(9342): Total time taken: 14
I/(9342): Total time taken: 16
I/(9342): Total time taken: 13
I/(9342): Total time taken: 28
I/(9342): Total time taken: 14
I/(9342): Total time taken: 12
I/(9342): Total time taken: 14
I/(9342): Total time taken: 19
I/(9342): Total time taken: 13
I/(9342): Total time taken: 13
```

Average => ~ 15.6 ms => 64 drawables per second

> **RenderScript (radius = 3) + Scaling (20%)**:

This is another way of getting a decent(?) but *fast* blur. What we do is scale the bitmap to a fraction of its size - say 20% - and apply the blur algorithm on the scaled down version. Once that is done, we scale the bitmap to its original size. Results are not as good as using the blur algorithm on the original, but they are passable. Also notice that the radius value shouldn't be too high or the resulting bitmap will be indiscernible.

What it looks like:

[image]

Logged time(ms) to generate each `BitmapDrawable`:

```
I/(11631): Total time taken: 5
I/(11631): Total time taken: 19
I/(11631): Total time taken: 3
I/(11631): Total time taken: 7
I/(11631): Total time taken: 7
I/(11631): Total time taken: 5
I/(11631): Total time taken: 7
I/(11631): Total time taken: 17
I/(11631): Total time taken: 5
I/(11631): Total time taken: 4
```

Average => ~ 7.9 ms => 126 drawables per second

> **StackBlur (radius = 3) + Scaling (20%)**:

Same concept as #3 above. Reduce size to 20% and apply stackblur on the scaled bitmap.

[image]

```
I/(12690): Total time taken: 4
I/(12690): Total time taken: 20
I/(12690): Total time taken: 4
I/(12690): Total time taken: 4
I/(12690): Total time taken: 5
I/(12690): Total time taken: 5
I/(12690): Total time taken: 4
I/(12690): Total time taken: 21
I/(12690): Total time taken: 3
I/(12690): Total time taken: 4
```

Average => ~ 7.4 ms => 135 drawables per second

Tests carried out on Nex4.
Bitmap size - 200px x 200px

**Another tip**: methods `buildDrawingCache()` and `getDrawingCache()` themselves take a long time. An alternative to this is to create a Bitmap using the dimensions of the view you need to blur:

```
Bitmap toDrawOn = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewWidth, viewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

// Create a canvas - assign `toDrawOn` as an offscreen bitmap to it
Canvas holdingCanvas = new Canvas(toDrawOn);

// Now, let the view draw itself on this canvas
yourView.draw(holdingCanvas);
```

The view is now drawn on `toDrawOn` and you can use it however you please.

This, in my experience is much faster than generating and accessing a view's drawing cache.

If you need help implementing any of the 4 methods listed above, let me know in comments.

Do keep in mind that the gifs above have been downscaled and whatnot. If you'd like to see original screen-capture (mp4) files - check this [Link](http://ge.tt/77kPl8i1/v/0?c).

Comment: +1. This is a fantastic answer, Vikram! You sure walk that extra mile in not only providing an answer but also perform and share the results of quite sophisticated experiments. God bless!

Comment: Hi ! Your answer is awesome. Do we need to use a custom class View ? Because I don't see where we do the blurring while drawing... so thanks in advance !

Comment: It would be better if there are source examples.

Answer (score 17):

[Here](https://plus.google.com/+MarioViviani/posts/fhuzYkji9zz?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=0ebb6e887b-Android_Weekly_103&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-0ebb6e887b-337837333) is a good way to "Blur Images Efficiently using Renderscript" by GDE [Mario Viviani](https://plus.google.com/100707738835400160066).

Here is the copy/paste:

Blurring images is an effect a lot of developers need to achieve, and it may require some time and efforts to be implemented. Also, since a lot of image manipulation is required, if it's not appropriately coded it can be really a pain in terms of CPU and memory usage.

There's a quick and efficient solution to blur images, which is [Renderscript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html).

Available since [API 11](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.0.html) (`Honeycomb`), `Renderscript` allows to take advantage of the GPU acceleration and is targeted at high-performance 3D rendering and compute operations.
`Renderscript` is a really complex and articulated product, and allows deep configuration and coding using native C99 language, which allows portability, performance and usability.

However, since [API 17](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html) (4.2.2) `Renderscript` offer some built-in functions that perform well-defined operations, called Intrinsics.
Intrinsics are pre-written scripts that allow,  to perform operations like Blur, Blen, Matrix Convolution and more, without the need to write `Renderscript` code.

Here's a simple method I wrote to easily end efficiently apply a Blur filter to a Bitmap:

```
public Bitmap blurBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

    //Let's create an empty bitmap with the same size of the bitmap we want to blur
    Bitmap outBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);

    //Instantiate a new Renderscript
    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(getApplicationContext());

    //Create an Intrinsic Blur Script using the Renderscript
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur blurScript = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));

    //Create the in/out Allocations with the Renderscript and the in/out bitmaps
    Allocation allIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap);
    Allocation allOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outBitmap);

    //Set the radius of the blur
    blurScript.setRadius(25.f);

    //Perform the Renderscript
    blurScript.setInput(allIn);
    blurScript.forEach(allOut);

    //Copy the final bitmap created by the out Allocation to the outBitmap
    allOut.copyTo(outBitmap);

    //recycle the original bitmap
    bitmap.recycle();

    //After finishing everything, we destroy the Renderscript.
    rs.destroy();

    return outBitmap;
}
```

[image: RenderScript Blurred Image]

And...voilà! Blurred bitmap! :-)

Remember that to run the previous code you need minimum API 17 (4.2.2).

Here's a Gist of this method:
https://gist.github.com/Mariuxtheone/903c35b4927c0df18cf8

If you want to discover more about Intrinsics, check out this post on Android Developers Blog:
http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2013/08/renderscript-intrinsics.html

If you're interested in know more about Renderscript, check out these links:
http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2011/02/introducing-renderscript.html
http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2011/03/renderscript.html

Comment: About it requires minimum api level 17, there is a RenderScript support library for api level 8+ http://android-developers.blogspot.com.tr/2013/09/renderscript-in-android-support-library.html . Also `RenderScript.create` takes some time so instead of creating it everytime in your `blurBitmap` method, you should create the script once and use it every time by changing in and out parameters.

Comment: Can this be used to blur only part of an image like the sample image?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it easily, using layout features.

I would suggest drawing parent view to canvas as described here: [How to make any view to draw to canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531858/how-to-make-any-view-to-draw-to-canvas) with the foreground view hidden. Then, blur the canvas and draw the foreground view using this data as a background, or a part of it.

It will be very resource intensive operation if you want this effect to be live. You should at least try caching the blur result.

Answer (score 0):

step 1. cut the part of background image in bitmap which is to be blured.

step 2. Blur that part of bitmap.

step 3. set bitmap as a background.

#### java method

```
private void applyBlur(final View image, final View layout) {
image.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            image.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            image.buildDrawingCache();

            Bitmap bmp = image.getDrawingCache();

            Bitmap overlay = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) (layout.getMeasuredWidth()),
                    (int) (layout.getMeasuredHeight()), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlay);

            canvas.translate(-layout.getLeft(), -layout.getTop());
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);

            RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(getActivity());

            Allocation overlayAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(
                    rs, overlay);

            ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(
                    rs, overlayAlloc.getElement());

            blur.setInput(overlayAlloc);

            blur.setRadius(20);

            blur.forEach(overlayAlloc);

            overlayAlloc.copyTo(overlay);

            layout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(
                    getResources(), overlay));

            rs.destroy();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

#### ...

now call this function:

#### calling method

applyBlur(detail_main_image, titleLayout);

#### ...

//where detail_main_image is image on which i have to show blur part
//and titleLayout is view on which i have to set background blur.

Answer (score -1):

If you're creating a custom view for this you can use the **maskFilter** property to make the view blur:

```
private val paint = Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
private val path = Path()

init {
    paint.maskFilter = BlurMaskFilter(15f, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL)
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    ...
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As of Android 31+, **RenderEffect** is a new API that handles all of this natively.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RenderEffect

Example:

```
view.setRenderEffect(RenderEffect.createBlurEffect(blurRadiusX, blurRadiusY, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
```

Another example: https://medium.com/poqcommerce/rendereffect-using-androids-new-api-to-solve-image-rendering-problems-90f7d7c49127

Comment: That option only blurs the contents of the view, not what is underneath. The question was asking how to blur anything underneath the view, which this API fails to achieve.

Comment: My solution was to make a bitmap copy of the content underneath the view, and whenever that view changes, update the bitmap. So it effectively did the same thing.

Comment: that's not clear in your answer, there's only 2 links which might stop working some day, and even considering what you just said that means yours is a duplicate of the answer posted by indrajeet in 2016.