# Is there a google official solution for making blur effect on a view?

Tags: android

I need to make blur overlay on text or image views. Is there a google official solution for that?

P.S. or you might share good solution you used

I have checked this topic already [Android Blur View (Blur background behind the view)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808955/android-blur-view-blur-background-behind-the-view)

Comment: What your want to achieve and on which view. Also show the code tht u hv tried so far!

Comment: @PrajwalW i have nothing to show yet. I want to have layout which will be over text view and by default it will be disabled but after trigger it become enabled and text view will be blured

Comment: You want the blur effect? on Iamgeview background?

Comment: @PrajwalW on image view OR text view. So it suppose to like a container which I can turn on or turn off

Comment: Renderscript..!!

Comment: You can try putting a overlay and then animate it based on alpha

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of making textView blur is :

```
textView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_id);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            textView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        float radius = textView.getTextSize() / 3;
        BlurMaskFilter filter = new BlurMaskFilter(radius, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
        textView.getPaint().setMaskFilter(filter);
```