# How to give semi-transparent (translucent) look to the whole layout and make it look normal again after the onclick of an icon in toolbar in Android?

Tags: android

I need to make the layout semi-transparent as my app opens and make it look back normal again after the onclick of and icon that I have set in the toolbar

Comment: So what issue are you facing ?

Comment: did you try anything ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `MainActivity.java`

Add below line for declaration.

`public LinearLayout linearlayout;`

Add below two lines in `onCreate` of `MainActivity.java`

```
linearLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
linearLayout.setAlpha((float) 0.5);
```

And write below line on `onclick()` of your icon, on whose `onclick()` you need to make it look normal again.

```
linearlayout.setAlpha((float) 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

set alpha in your xml layout for blur image.

Comment: alpha? for blur effect?

Comment: Yes.Or you can see also this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780006/transparent-blurry-view-which-blurs-layout-underneath

Comment: do you know what alpha is? and how is it related to image bluring?

Comment: In xml:
android:alpha="0.5"
or in code

yourView.getBackground().setAlpha(100);

Comment: @pskink actually you can set alpha from your mainActivity.java also. Set it as linearlayout.setAlpha((float) 0.5) to make it blur and write linearlayout.setAlpha((float)1) to make it completely normal again......... (0) make it completely transperant, I am not sure regarding zero.

Comment: @YeshaShah alpha has nothing to do with [blurring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur), if you want semi transparent look use alpha but as i said it is not blurring

Answer (score 0):

You can create blurred bitmap from a background image or view then set it as background.I used the below class to create a blurred bitmap

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.Allocation;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.Element;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur;
import android.view.View;

public class BlurBuilder {
        private static final float BITMAP_SCALE = 0.2f;
        private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 20f;

        public static Bitmap blur(View v) {
            return blur(v.getContext(), getScreenshot(v));
        }

        public static Bitmap blur(Context ctx, Bitmap image) {
            int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
            int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);

            Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
            Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

            RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(ctx);
            ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
            Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
            Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);
            theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
            theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
            theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
            tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

            return outputBitmap;
        }

        private static Bitmap getScreenshot(View v) {
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
            v.draw(c);
            return b;
        }
    }
```

Then

```
 mBackgroundBlurBitmap = BlurBuilder.blur(this, mBackgroundBitmap);
```