# How to make the background of my popup blur not just transparent

Tags: android, popup

hello every one i'm new to android i build this app and i want to make the background blur when i click on the list , not just transparent i made it transparent with adding

`<style name="AppTheme.Popuptheme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    </style>`

in my style.xml file

this is my popup class

```
  package com.example.jihad.smsbalanceparser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

/**
 * Created by AMD on 1/6/2018.
 */

public class Pop extends Activity {

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.popup);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;

        getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.6));





}
}
```

and this is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jihad.smsbalanceparser">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="SMS Balance Manager"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".SMSReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name=".Pop" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Popuptheme" >

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

finally this is my popup.xml file which is my pop-up layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:popup="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_gravity="center"


    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"


    >


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780006/transparent-blurry-view-which-blurs-layout-underneath)

Comment: extent dialogActivity  that will work for you

Answer (score 1):

Blur effect is obtained in really complex way like taking current screen shot and rendering it.

[This Library](https://github.com/tvbarthel/BlurDialogFragment)
does all the work.
May be this will help you.