# Activity Background transparency and blur

Tags: android

I am trying to achieve a transparent background with a blurry effect on it. I managed to made the activity transparent but no luck with the blur. Could you help me to figure this out? I attached an image with contains what I would like to achieve(that blurry background below settings app).Thank you.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFE5o.jpg)

Comment: Check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780006/transparent-blurry-view-which-blurs-layout-underneath

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent blurry view which blurs layout underneath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780006/transparent-blurry-view-which-blurs-layout-underneath)

Comment: Hello, that topic didn't solve my problem. I am not trying to blur an image, I am trying to blur the whole screen including status bar and navbar as you can see in the picture I attached. When I am opening the second activity from the main activity I want to see all that is in main activity blurred out.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Blurry](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry) library to achieve blur effect. It works perfect, but has minor bugs with activity state recreation (please check out issues)