# How to blur a video view?

Tags: android

I want to blur a videoview which is playing a video from raw folder.

Blurring a imageview or a layout containing drawable background is possible using renderscript or libraries like Blurry. But how to blur a video? I tried methods like converting uri path of video to bitmap, video to thumbnail but didn't work.

Here is my code.

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.MediaController
import android.widget.VideoView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView) as VideoView
    val mediaController = MediaController(this)
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)
    val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.samplevideo)
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
    videoView.requestFocus()
    videoView.start()

    var runnable = Runnable {


        var resultBmp = BlurBuilder.blur(this, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.raw.samplevideo))
        var drawable = BitmapDrawable(resources, resultBmp)
        videoView.background = drawable

    }

    videoView.post(runnable)
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

BlurBuilder.kt

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.renderscript.Allocation;
import android.renderscript.Element;
import android.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur;

object BlurBuilder {

private val BITMAP_SCALE = 0.6f
private val BLUR_RADIUS = 15f

fun blur(context: Context, image: Bitmap): Bitmap {
    val width = Math.round(image.width * BITMAP_SCALE)
    val height = Math.round(image.height * BITMAP_SCALE)

    val inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false)
    val outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap)

    val rs = RenderScript.create(context)

    val intrinsicBlur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs))
    val tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap)
    val tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap)

    intrinsicBlur.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS)
    intrinsicBlur.setInput(tmpIn)
    intrinsicBlur.forEach(tmpOut)
    tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap)

    return outputBitmap
}
```

}

Please help me in blurring video view or relative layout containing the video view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780006/transparent-blurry-view-which-blurs-layout-underneath can be useful.

Comment: are you able to achieve that ? i have similar requirement