# How to make image blur in android

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, whatsapp

I am developing a chat application, i need to blur a bitmap,when user is scrolling list i will show blur image instead of original images.

If we  blur a bitmap is there any change in bitmap size

please let me know how much time it will take to blur a bitmap and what will be the change in bitmap size

Comment: Look at [blur-a-image-at-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743969/blur-a-image-at-android)

Comment: It seems to similar of these questions :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972733/how-to-make-image-blur-in-android?rq=1 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276967/blurring-an-image-in-android?lq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728860/blur-and-emboss-an-image/6744104#6744104

Comment: thank you for reply how much time it will take to blur a image, and what will be the change regarding to bitmap size

Answer (score 1):

create a SurfaceView and use the FX_SURFACE_BLUR flag?
Reference link-http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html#FX_SURFACE_BLUR